# Eloquent. Структура БД для игры в морской бой

Tags: база-данных, eloquent

Я собираюсь делать игру **"Морской бой"**. У меня есть таблица **GameTables**, в которой я собираюсь хранить, какие два игрока сейчас играют за одним столиком. Но, если сделать два столбца, ссылкающиеся на таблицу **Players**, то тогда возникают проблемы с созданием связей между таблицами **Eloquent**. Скажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить? Я думал на счёт того, чтобы сделать разные таблицы под игрока №1 и игрока №2. Например, чтобы в таблице **GameTables** хранилось: **id**, **first_player_id**(ссылка на таблицу **FirstPlayers**), **second_player_id**(ссылка на таблицу **SecondPlayers**), но не уверен, что так будет правильно.

Comment: GameTables хранилось: id, first_player_id ссылка на Players, second_player_id ссылка на Players. Проблема не в том, что не Eloquent так не умеет, а в том что вы не умеете так делать. Советую прочитать внимательней документацию

Comment: Я погуглил и вроде как нашёл решение своей проблемы. Нужно сделать самореферное отношение между players и players. https://coderoad.ru/53222776/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-JOIN-%D0%B2-Laravel-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0